# Settings bundle for ios8 custom keyboard still not working

Tags: ios8, xcode6, settings.bundle, ios-app-extension

ios 8 final version is released, however settings bundle for custom keyboard is still not working.
am I doing something wrong or there is something that i don't know?

I'm creating Settings.bundle file for custom keyboard extension, going with default values.
For example there is Toggle Switch row in settings bundle, which default value is YES, so it means that inside the device Settings in Keyboards section I should see the Switch control with Yes state, ok, this step is working good, but when I change the state of switch control , the settings bundle is not getting updated, so after reopening settings page the Switch value is still YES, the question is WHY ? I've already changed it to NO.

the next case is when I'm using the settings bundle with App Groups, it doesn't matter what Default value you set in Root.plist,  you always should see Switch with value of NO.

Maybe anyone found workaround for these issues ?

Comment: I have the same issues. It seems that Apple made release with such epic bugs.